# lenovo P50, nouveau vs. nvidia drivers, resolution problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution, nouveau

Really old and persistent problem with proprietary nvidia drivers... If I enable nouveau graphic driver in my kubuntu 17.04 installed on lenovo P50 there are really many resolutions available in displays settings starting from really "small" up to native 3840x2160, that's great. But, when I switch to any version of nvidia proprietary driver there is only native resolution(3840x2160) available, nothing else. Is there a way how can I fix it? No solution using "scaling" is acceptable of course. Nvidia drivers are much faster on other side, but because of this I cannot use it e.g. for presentation...

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't yet comment, I'll provide some possible solutions that may or may not work as well since originally, as a comment, I wanted to ask what your BIOS settings was set to when attempting to switch to the proprietary drivers? And, are you running on Hybdrid Graphics or Discrete Graphics?

Then, if so, I might've suggested changing your BIOS settings to discrete graphics (or the other if already set as discrete) to see if perhaps the limitation on available resolutions is due to the wrong driver being applied to the active graphics processor.

Some suggestions for other possible solutions to your question:

**1. Install The Nvidia-Settings Package**

Make sure you have `nvidia-settings` installed, it is included usually with the Nvidia Linux graphics driver but since it remains open how you installed the drivers (from repository, nvidia website, software updater, etc.), you can check if it's installed or [install](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/nvidia-settings/) it if needed

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-settings

# Then to run simply

$ sudo nvidia-settings
```

For more on how to use nvidia-settings, go [here](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/nvidia_settings/).

**2. Reconfiguring/Reinstalling the Display manager**

After switching to the proprietary drivers (which I'm not sure if that means a driver uninstall and install or a change in BIOS but assumes it works without other known issues) is to try reconfiguring your display manager and/or reinstalling the package for it so that it reconfigures itself to be used with the proprietary drivers upon switching:

```
# replace {Display Manager} with whatever you're using, or otherwise

$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure {Display manager}


# for the default of Kubuntu, it's sddm:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm


# Or if that makes no difference, you could try reinstalling

sudo apt-get install --reinstall sddm
```

Although the process of 'switching drivers' wasn't described in full, it was assumed that the normal steps were taken and still resulted in this problem, specifically, restarting after installing the proprietary drivers as that might prevent such issues from arising, but could go unnoted if checking display settings immediately after installing that would've motivated an uninstall before any system reboot occurred.

**3. Use Added Software xrandr**

A guest user reported being able to add previously unavailable resolutions to their install of Kubuntu 13.10 for an external display using `xrandr` [here](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forum/newbie-support/help-the-new-guy/58055-custom-display-resolution). That same thread, to make the changes permanent, also mentions making an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file (AKA the X Display Manager [config file](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config)) so that it's actually used by the system, since Kubuntu doesn't come standard with it.
With help from [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-your-monitors-with-xrandr-in-linux), a quick overview of the steps look something like this:

```
# Determine properties of your display

xrandr -q

# To manually set the resolution for when you make presentations
# and say it's hooked in through DVI port, desiring 1080p resolution 
# running at 60Hz refresh rate, it would be

xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60.00

# To actually add the resolution, as taken from the guest post as an example
# You just need to replace the string of numbers for '--newmode' with
# the output shown from 'xrandr -q' and remove any unnecessary options

xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 85.25 1368 1440 1576 1784 768 771 781 798 -hsync -vsync

xrandr --addmode DVI-D-0 1920x1080

xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --mode 1920x1080
```

More on `xrandr` can be found [here](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html).

Hopefully that helps anyone who happens to stumble across this since this question was asked 5 years ago and the OP probably already figured something out, hopefully.